# Regex regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm programming a calculator in C# to begin with that. 
I will separate a string in two variables= Nb1 and Nb2. I looked on the web for examples and I found something :

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
var match = numAlpha.Match("codename123");
var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value; // Alpha = codename
var num = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value; // Numeric = 123
```

I fails to only adapt for the numbers : " 121165468746*1132" or "4586/6953" 
Nb1 =121165468746 || 4586
Nb2 =1132 || 6953

Can you help me ? I'm going crazy  :-)

Comment: Have you tried to read some documentation for Regex? What you have will not match your input.

Comment: What should it return for number-only sequences?

Comment: @Eve: It will; the quantifier is `*`, not `+`.

Comment: @minitech I'm referring to his other "numbers", not the string in his code. I assumed he wants to extract those two numbers with the Regex -- In case I'm wrong, I'll remove the comments. Even if it still matches, I think it's not what the poster expects.

Comment: The code is just a  example. I would make the same thing with numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<NumOne>[0-9]+)(?<Operator>[^0-9])(?<NumTwo>[0-9]+)");
var match = numAlpha.Match("121165468746*1132");
var nb1 = match.Groups["NumOne"].Value; // nb1 = 121165468746
var nb2 = match.Groups["NumTwo"].Value; // nb2 = 1132
var op = match.Groups["Operator"].Value; // op = *
```

It looks like what you're trying to do is match some pair of integers separated by an operator.  The above regex uses named groups `(?<GroupName> ... )`, and two simple regular expressions to achieve that.  `[0-9]+` will match one or more digits, and `[^0-9]` will match any one non-digit character, which here is being assumed to be the operator.

If this isn't what you were looking for, leave a comment and I'll try to help you out.  In the mean time, some reading material:

- [Regular Expressions Page, with plenty of tutorials and references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Javascript Regular Expressions Tester with Syntax Highlighting](http://regexpal.com)
- [Java RegEx Tester.  More powerful, fewer frills.](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this pattern for your Regex: it assumes that there are at least two numbers with one or more digits, separated by one or more non-digit characters (in case the operator is not only one character). The groups are called `n1` and `n2`.

```
^(?<n1>\d+)[^\d]+?(?<n2>\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to match numbers with predefined 4 basic operations Multiply, Subtract, Add, Divide. You can add more operators to the "op" expressions as per your need.

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"(?<num1>[0-9]+)(?<op>[\*\-\+\\])(?<num2>[0-9]+)");
```